# passing parameters with c# to powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, pipeline

I am trying to pass a string from my c# app to my powershell script .

I keep geting an error:"A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument `'$null'`
what should I do?

my c# code:

```
  public void PowerShell()
    {
        RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
        runspace.Open();
        RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);

        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

        String scriptfile = @"c:\test.ps1";

        Command myCommand = new Command(scriptfile, false);

        CommandParameter testParam = new CommandParameter("username", "serverName");

        myCommand.Parameters.Add(testParam);


        pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);
        Collection<PSObject> psObjects;
        psObjects = pipeline.Invoke(); <---error- "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null'" 
        runspace.Close();

    }
```

my powershell code:

```
 Out-Host  $username
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PS script have no parameters, it simply uses variable. So, try this instead:

```
Param($username)
Write-Output $username
```

Please, notice that Out-Host is not acceptable in you case, because it tries to output param to calling scope, not simply write something to output stream.

Also, you can set variable in runspace, so it will be available in script without params:

```
runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("username", "SomeUser");
```

(it must be done after runspace.Open() and before pipeline.Invoke())

Comment: i changed my powershell script to: "Param($username)
Out-Host $username" as advised but now i get error: "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'serverName'."

Comment: Try change "Param($username)" to "Param($serverName)"

Comment: now i get:"A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null'" agin... :\

Comment: I got it. You must use Write-Host instead of Out-Host.

It will not work, even if you will write something like following in powershell:
Out-Host "test"

Comment: almost arrrr now i get this:"Cannot invoke this function because the current host does not implement it." what function is he talking about there is no function in my ps script...

Comment: Powershell is amazing in creating troubles) Use Write-Output instead of Write-Host. When it says, that there are no such function, it means, that you hosting powershell runspace, and not implement output console.